# vscode line breaking when typing

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

vscode line breaking when typing

When I type, it breaks the line at every word. I've seen several settings on the internet but none works.

I also removed ESLINT and PRETTIER.

What can I do?

[image]

Comment: Try disabling autosave before figuring out the actual proper solution

Comment: Autosave has already been removed, and the problem continues.

Comment: Some ideas: What extensions do you have installed? What is your setting.config? Also try checking the keybinding and see if the key presses might be triggering anything funny (or what they might be invoking anyway): [troubleshoot keybindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_troubleshooting-keybindings)

Comment: I found it, it was the "EditorConfig for VsCode" extension